# array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am facing some issue and this about array_merge in laravel
My Controller code method:

```
    public function isConnectedMA()
{
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    if(!empty($user_id)) {
        $isConnectedM = DB::table('user_mlc_mailchimp')->where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
        $isConnectedA = DB::table('user_mlc_aweber')->where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
    }
        $MergeArray = array_merge($isConnectedM,$isConnectedA);
    $resultArray = ['status' => 1, 'message' => 'Template uploaded!', 'dataArray' => $MergeArray];
    return Response::json($resultArray,200);

}
```

the error i am facing is

> array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array

i dont know where i am wrong 
any help will be highly appreciated !

Comment: You could check `var_dump($isConnectedM);` and `var_dump($isConnectedA);`

Answer (score 7):

Use [toArray()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-toarray) to convert `collections` to array

```
$isConnectedM = DB::table('user_mlc_mailchimp')->where('user_id', $user_id)->get()->toArray();
$isConnectedA = DB::table('user_mlc_aweber')->where('user_id', $user_id)->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: ok i have solved my problem but here is i am facing one more issue

Comment: You can see i put a condition if(!empty)  and after that i want to check if this is empty and show some kind of message but i am trying to do this but i am getting unreachable statement.

Comment: @shahzad1122 yes, go on, explain your new problem

Answer (score 1):

In laravel `->get();` returns the collection object, you should user `->toArray()` here.

Answer (score 1):

$isConnectedM and $isConnectedA is Collection object.
`Response::json($collection,200);` automatic collection object to json conversion

```
$MergeArray = $isConnectedM->merge($isConnectedA) ;
$resultArray = ['status' => 1, 'message' => 'Template uploaded!', 'dataArray' => $MergeArray];
return Response::json($resultArray,200);
```

Comment: ok i have solved my problem but here is i am facing one more issue

Comment: You can see i put a condition if(!empty)  and after that i want to check if this is empty and show some kind of message but i am trying to do this but i am getting unreachable statement.

Comment: i dont inderstand enough.
` if(!empty) ` collection object .is ...
→ `if($isConnectedM->isEmpty())` or `if($isConnectedM->count() > 0)`

Comment: @fumi, thanks, you save my lot of time

Answer (score 0):

@shahzad,
Reason for the issue for array_merge we've to pass two arrays, if we didn't pass then it will throw an error.

```
 public function isConnectedMA() {
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    // If user id is not passed, return or redirect to login page.
    if (empty($user_id) {
        // TODO : Do logic to retun
        $resultArray = ['status' => 0, 'message' => 'OOPS! seems like user is not logged in.', 'dataArray' => []];
        return Response::json($resultArray, 401);
    }

    $isConnectedM = DB::table('user_mlc_mailchimp')->where('user_id', $user_id)->get()->toArray();
    $isConnectedA = DB::table('user_mlc_aweber')->where('user_id', $user_id)->get()->toArray();
    $MergeArray = array_merge($isConnectedM,$isConnectedA); // array_merge((array)$isConnectedM, (array)$isConnectedA);
    $resultArray = ['status' => 1, 'message' => 'Template uploaded!', 'dataArray' => $MergeArray];
    return Response::json($resultArray,200);
}
```

**Reference** arry_merge - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: its not going on if(empty($user_id) condition

Comment: @shahzad1122, then print/debug what is the value of $user_id. and check in the database whether is there a record with the given id or not.

Before merging the two arrays, check what is the output of these -  ``$isConnectedM = DB::table('user_mlc_mailchimp')->where('user_id', $user_id)->get()``

Answer (score 0):

`$isConnectedM` and `$isConnectedA` are not `arrays`. You can also use `typecast` to convert an `object` to `array`.

```
$isConnectedM = (array) DB::table('user_mlc_mailchimp')->where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
$isConnectedA = (array) DB::table('user_mlc_aweber')->where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
```